# Irreducibility of sums of two polynomials

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, factoring, irreducible-polynomials

I'm interested in a special type of polynomial factorization over $\mathbb {Q} $: testing the irreducibility of $f(x)+g(x)$, where $f$ and $g $ are relatively prime and $\text {deg}(f)<\text{deg}(g) $. For ease, let me assume the coefficients are integers.

Surely, there are a bunch of nonexamples; $(2x)+(1+x^2)$, $(x)+(-1-x+x^2)$, and so on. To make the problem meaningful, we should impose some limitations on $f$ and $g$. After a brief googling, I found only two results directly related to the topic above: some Schur-type results http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00605-010-0241-9 and a research paper http://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/S1793042113500413 .

Hm. How about just monomial $f$, and/or some reducible $g $, with $2\text {deg}(f)\le\text{deg}(g) $? It is the very condition for Schur-type results. In particular, I want to classify(or just find) reducible $g $'s with $\text{deg}(g)=2n$, $f(x)=x^n $ and $g $ having many (at least 11) irreducible factors, making $x^n+g (x) $ reducible. Is it possible?

Comment: ($x^3+x+1$) + ($x^8+x^5+x^4+x^3+1$) =  $(x+1)^2 \left(x^2-x+1\right) \left(x^4-x^3+x^2-x+2\right)$

Comment: This example will show you how to construct the kind of thing you want. Let $g(x)=-(x-4)^4(x-3)^4$ of degree 8 with 8 irreducible factors, then $x^4+g(x)$ is reducible (it has $x-6$ as a factor).

Comment: Any thoughts on my comment?